# "Unresolved reference kotlinx" エラー

Tags: android, java, android-studio, kotlin

android studioを1.3.2にアップグレードしたらエラーが出ました。

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity_userpage.pager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity_userpage.tabs
```

"kotlinx"の部分が赤文字でカーソルを合わせると"Unresolved reference kotlinx"と出ます。
電球マークを開くと”create package  '〜〜〜〜〜〜app.activities.kotlinx'”と書いてあります。

解決方法がわかる方お願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I don't know Japanese but Chrome was able to translate the page. I had this same issue and fixed it by adding:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

To my dependencies in my kotlin buildpath in my apps build.gradle

---

私は日本語がわかりません。ですがChromeで翻訳することができました。私も同じ問題を持っていましたがこれを追加することで修正できました。

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

`build.gradle`の`dependencies`にこのビルドパスを追加してください。